# create facebook like notification system in django

Tags: django, notifications, web-development-server, django-notification

Say user a liked user b. I want to show this as a notification in the notification panel of user b when she logs in. She can also view her previous notifications (basically like facebook notification). This is not `email notification` or a `success/warning` type one time notification.

I want to know the right track to follow. Do I use [`django-notifications`](https://github.com/django-notifications/django-notifications) or [django-messages-framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/) or [`push notifications`](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-send-web-push-notifications-from-django-applications)? Where is the use of `channels` and `web sockets` in all of these?

My steps:

1) create a notification app

2) create a notification model (what fields do I put here if since `django-notification` already has `actor, verb, action object and target` fields?)

3) Do i have to create `forms.py`? How is the notification message getting passed?

4) What view do I put in `views.py`? (please give an example code)

If there is any example project that implemented the `notification system` please provide a link.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using [django-notifications](https://github.com/django-notifications/django-notifications) you can just create an object with the actor as user_a, verb as `'like`' or any other action performed, recipient would be user_b

So something like

```
notify.send(request.user, verb='liked', recipient=[target_user])
```

When user_b logs in you can fetch all the notification (or maybe just the unread ones) and display it

```
user.notifications.active()
user.notifications.unread()
```